# Excel VBA Application.Find() Method

Tags: excel, vba, object

Based on Microsoft VBA docs, I know there's `Range.Find(What, After, LookIn, Lookat, SearchOrder....)`, but there is no `Application.Find()` method. And if I go to the **Object Browser** in **VBE** to inspect the *Application* object, I still not see any *Find* method attached to *Application* object. And it makes sense there is no intellisense when I type "Application.Find("

However, The Application.Find() method just works.

```
txt = "EEZ || EZE 123"
pos = Application.Find(" ", txt, 1)
```

the pos will have value 4. Why? ... no docs, no method in the object browser, the method can still work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Application.Find` is an extended member of the `Excel.Application` interface.. it's pretty much tacked-on at runtime, that's why it's not showing anywhere. The COM type for `Excel.Application` is  *extensible*, and extended with what appears to be members of the `WorksheetFunction` interface, but through the Excel calculation engine (or at least, consistent with how Excel would evaluate it) rather than through the VBA runtime.

In other words this:

```
Debug.Print Application.Find("4", "12345", 1)
```

Is pretty much this:

```
Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("4", "12345", 1)
```

The difference is more obvious when you give them invalid parameters:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(Application.Find("4", "12345", 10))
Debug.Print TypeName(Application.WorksheetFunction.Find("4", "12345", 10))
```

The first prints `Error`, the second throws run-time error 1004, allowing for more idiomatic error handling (i.e. an `On Error` statement will kick in). The `Error` type can't be converted to any other VBA type, so expect run-time error 13 "type mismatch" if you try to assign it to a `String`, or anything other than a `Variant`. The `IsError` function returns `True` given a `Variant/Error` variable/expression.

If you need to locate the position of a substring inside a `String`, use the `VBA.Strings.InStr` function:

```
Debug.Print InStr(1, "12345", "4", vbTextCompare)
```

Note the order of the parameters, and the additional `VbCompareMethod` parameter that makes a case-insensitive search with `vbTextCompare`, a case-sensitive search with `vbBinaryCompare`, and if you're in Access, `vbDatabaseCompare` matches the comparison method of the current database. If omitted, `Option Compare` specified at module level determines the parameter value; `Option Compare Binary` being the default.

Invoking early-bound VBA standard library functions should incur less run-time overhead than querying `IDispatch` on an `Object` to locate a `Find` function... and then get Excel to evaluate the result.

Other examples of extended interfaces include `ADODB.Connection`, against which you *can* (whether you *should* is another question!) invoke a stored procedure as you would a member call - note that here again, *intellisense* can't help, and `Option Explicit` will turn a blind eye, for these calls are always late-bound (i.e. resolved at run-time).

Comment: Thanks!! a comprehensive explain~~      At runtime `Application.Find` is extended via Excel calculation engine to `Application.worksheetfunction.find`. um...cool~

Comment: There's no reason to use either in VBA code: use `InStr` instead.

Comment: A small nit: by default all COM types are extensible. One must explicitly mark it as nonextensible to prevent additional methods getting tacked on an interface. In that case, Excel type didn't have to be marked as extensible.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed very interesting. It appears that this is a shortcut to Application.WorksheetFunction.Find. The Find method you are using is not the same as the VBA Find method for Range.Find, it is the same as the worksheet function Find.

I also tested other Worksheet Functions and they all appear to also work: Application.Sum, Application.Count. But others already have a defined Application method (such as Application.Left does not shortcut to Worksheet Function).

Comment: Thanks for your time into this. ~~~   I am so confused when I find this, lol.  BTW, I prefer still use the full qualifier in the future. The shortcut way can be confusing.

Comment: Your last sentence is incorrect. There's no `WorksheetFunction.Left` to begin with. One would use the `VBA.Strings.Left` (or shorter, `Left`) function, which is from the VBA standard library, not the Excel `Application`.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Yes, there is no `WorksheetFunction.Left`. But there is a '=Left()' function in the actual worksheet interface - which is what I was referring to. My understanding from the OP was they were confusing the parameters between '=Find()' on the worksheet and `Application.Find` in VBA.