# Is "Application.Replace" in VBA/Excel an undocumented function?

Tags: excel, vba

I just discovered the function "Application.Replace" in VBA/Excel, with different features than "VBA.Replace":

Examples:

```
Application.Replace("fooobar",3 ,1 , "O")
```

Result: "foOobar"

```
Application.Replace("fooobar",3 ,2 , "OO")
```

Result: "foOObar"

The third argument seems exclusive of Application.Replace and defines the length from the start position.

What surprised me is that I can't find this function in the object browser (it's not even an hidden member!) nor in the MS web [reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application(object)) for the Application object.

Is it an undocumented function?

Comment: It is the late-bound version of `WorksheetFunction.Replace`.

Comment: Similar explanation for `Application.Find` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625186/excel-vba-application-find-method). I'm voting to close as duplicate as the linked thread explains all relevant info, just for another `WorksheetFunction`.

Comment: All right, thanks!